# Get data based on other row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

[image: Example]

when a row of ID is void, it will not show the cc_type, but I need get the cc_type for those void rows.

```
CASE WHEN CC_TYPE = 'Credit' OR Voided = 'Yes' THEN 'Credit'
     WHEN CC_TYPE = 'Debit OR Voided = 'Yes' THEN 'Debit'
END
```

Obviously, this approach wouldn't work. Row 3 will consider as Credit to since it satisfy the condition for voided = 'Yes'.

My logic is if ID and Name are same then append the CC_Type value to Voided row, but I don't know how to get it work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a window function:

```
SELECT
  id,
  Name,
  MAX(CC_Type) OVER (PARTITION BY id, name) AS CC_Type,
  Voided
FROM
  yourtable
```

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me:

```
create table result as
  select a.id,a.name,b.cc_type,a.voided
from
 (select id, name,voided from table1) as a
inner join
 (select distinct id, cc_type from table1 where cc_type  ne "") as b
on a.id = b.id;
quit;
```

Comment: curious though, what happens if you have a customer that uses both a credit and debit card?

Comment: Generally avoid code-only answers.  Consider adding a `description` that helps to explain your code. _"this worked for me"_ is not suitable.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to update your table. The key idea here is that you can update the table using itself as a source.

```
UPDATE table1
SET table1.CC_Type = s.CC_Type
FROM table1 AS s
WHERE s.id = table1.id 
  AND s.name = table1.name 
  AND table1.Voided = 'Yes' 
  AND s.CC_Type <> ''
```